# Post action (copy files) after compile/build in "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: visual-studio-code, post-processing

I write TypeScript/JavaScript for SharePoint.  Because VSC can't open folders in WebDAV directly (gives an error), I have to develop on my PC, compile the code and copy manually (via batch file) the files to a SharePoint library.

**Question**: How can I automise within VSCode the copying of some files to a network drive, after I've done the compilation/build action (CTRL+Shift+B) of my TypeScript code?

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: I like the question, but this is more related to Super User or Sharepoint stackexchange. Not code related question.